# How many surfaces have $4$ edges...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

A 3 regular, plane, connected graph have all surfaces either $4$ or $6$ edges (including the outer surface). How many surfaces has $4$ edges?

Let $x$ be the number of surfaces that have $4$ edges

Let $y$ be the number of surfaces that have $6$ edges

Euler's formula gives:

$$v - e+ (x+y) = 2$$

I am stuck here. Ideally I would like another equation that has $x$ and $y$ in it so I thought of the one that says that the sum of the grade of every vertex is twice the edges.

$$3v = 2e$$

But it don't see how that would help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equations we have:

$$v-e+(x+y)=2,$$

$$3v=2e,$$

$$4x+6y=2e.$$

In the last equation, we count the pair of a face and an edge such that the face touches the edge.

On solving, $x=6$.

Comment: I don't understand. How can you be sure that you are not counting an edge multiple times when counting for example two surfaces. Can't two surfaces have common edges?

Comment: @DoubleOseven you can see that each edge is exactly touched by two faces. If you count by edges, then it is $2e$. If you count by faces, then it is $4x+6y$.

Comment: makes sense now, thank you!